# Make AVERAGE only for numerical values

Tags: google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula

I have some problem to build a dynamic `AVERAGE` in Google Sheets.
What I have here is this configuration.

I have a Cell A1, B2 and C3 that have another formula (like `IF`) that can return 2 different values: Numerical or `N/A`.
Then I have Cell D4 which keep the `AVERAGE` of cell A1, B2, C3.
The problem is that even if one of the above cells (A1, B2, C3) has `N/A` even the `AVERAGE` results returns `N/A`.

Are there any possibilities to make the `AVERAGE` working by ignoring `N/A` or any kind of texts and working only with Numbers?

This is the formula I have at the moment: `=AVERAGE(A1, B2, C3)`.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to wrap it into `IFERROR` like:

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(A1), IFERROR(B2), IFERROR(C3))
```

[image: 0]